# Does R use Tukey or Tukey-Kramer test corrected for unequal sample size and does it use the multivariate t distribution?

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, multivariate-normal-distribution, tukey-hsd-test

Does R use the classic Tukey HSD test for balanced data or corrects for unbalanced ones with the Tukey-Kramer approach? I mean the stats::TukeyHSD().

I found, that the Dunnet procedure uses multivariate t-distribution (for 2+ groups). Does Tukey HSD do the same? In R, I found that the multivariate t is calculated using the mvtnorm, which uses Monte Carlo simulations. Indeed, the results of Dunnet vary a little, if the seed is not set. But the outcomes of TukeyHSD are stable.

The R documentation only says that TukeyHSD works for mildly unbalanced data.

Comment: I corrected my question - it is about the basic stats::TukeyHSD(). I believe the method in glht works similarly, as it gives the same result.

Comment: In `glht`, "tukey" doesn't refer to Tukey's HSD.  It just means "do all pairwise comparisons".  By default, `ghlt` uses a "single-step" correction method, which I have a suspicion is a multivariate *t* approach, but I don't have anything that says that explicitly. But you could use a different correction method in `glht`...  Based on the documentation for `tukeyHSD`, I would assume it uses Tukey-Kramer.  You could always look at the code and try to figure it out...  For routine use, `glht` or `emmeans` might be more appropriate than traditional tests like Tukey HSD in some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `glht`, "tukey" doesn't refer to Tukey's HSD. It just means "do all pairwise comparisons". By default, `ghlt` uses a "single-step" correction method, but other correction methods could be used.

As far as I can tell, the `TukeyHSD` function uses the Tukey-Kramer procedure.  The code for the function can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/TukeyHSD.R). See also the example on [RPubs](https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/post-hoc-analysis-tukey).

At least for the simple case of a one-way design with equal variances in groups (but potentially unequal sample sizes), it appears that the results of `TukeyHSD` will match those of `emmeans` with a Tukey adjustment, and those of `glht` with a "single-step" adjustment.

```
if(!require(emmeans)){install.packages("emmeans")}
if(!require(multcomp)){install.packages("multcomp")}

set.seed(sum(utf8ToInt("Sal2020")))

A = rnorm(12, 5, 2)
B = rnorm(12, 7, 2)
C = rnorm(6,  9, 2)

Y     = c(A, B, C)
Group = factor(c(rep("A", length(A)), rep("B", length(B)), rep("C", length(C))))

AOV = aov(Y ~ Group)

TukeyHSD(AOV)

   ### Tukey multiple comparisons of means
   ###
   ###           diff        lwr      upr     p adj
   ### B-A  3.7733290  1.3694242 6.177234 0.0016529
   ### C-A  3.7450798  0.8009097 6.689250 0.0106113
   ### C-B -0.0282492 -2.9724192 2.915921 0.9996880

model = lm(Y ~ Group)

library(emmeans)

marginal = emmeans(model, ~ Group)

pairs(marginal, adjust="tukey")

    ###  contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
    ### A - B     -3.7733 0.97 27 -3.892  0.0017 
    ### A - C     -3.7451 1.19 27 -3.154  0.0106 
    ### B - C      0.0282 1.19 27  0.024  0.9997 

    ### P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates.

library(multcomp)

mc = glht(model, mcp(Group = "Tukey"))

summary(mc, test=adjusted("single-step"))

   ### Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
   ### 
   ###            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
   ### B - A == 0  3.77333    0.96954   3.892  0.00167 **
   ### C - A == 0  3.74508    1.18744   3.154  0.01053 * 
   ### C - B == 0 -0.02825    1.18744  -0.024  0.99969   
   ### 
   ### (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Likewise, it appears that the results of `emmeans` with no adjustment and those of `glht` with no adjustment, will match  those of `pairwise.t.test` with no adjustment.

```
pairwise.t.test(Y, Group, p.adjust.method = "none")

   ### Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 
   ###
   ###         A       B      
   ### B 0.00059 -      
   ### C 0.00393 0.98120
   ###
   ### P value adjustment method: none

pairs(marginal, adjust="none")

    ### contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
    ### A - B     -3.7733 0.97 27 -3.892  0.0006 
    ### A - C     -3.7451 1.19 27 -3.154  0.0039 
    ### B - C      0.0282 1.19 27  0.024  0.9812

summary(mc, test=adjusted("none"))

   ### Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
   ###
   ###            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   ### B - A == 0  3.77333    0.96954   3.892 0.000589 ***
   ### C - A == 0  3.74508    1.18744   3.154 0.003927 ** 
   ### C - B == 0 -0.02825    1.18744  -0.024 0.981195 
   ###
   ### (Adjusted p values reported -- none method)
```